# CKeditor removes certain parts when embedding twitter/instagram

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

for a client we are using ckeditor (4.6.2) and when you add the embed code of twitter or instagram (through the code toggle, so not through a plugin) and you save it, it's fine. The embedded widget are shown corretly on the site. But when you then edit the page again and you look at the embedded code, it removes stuff from it and it's not shown anymore or not correctly on the site. The website is build in regular PHP/HTML/CSS/MYSQL.

For example you add this to the editor:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="nl" dir="ltr">Tweede graffitispuiter komt uur nadat eerste vandaal werd weggejaagd terug om gevel <a href="\[https://twitter.com/hashtag/VlaamsBelang?src=hash\\\&amp;ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/hashtag/VlaamsBelang?src=hash\&amp;ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">#VlaamsBelang</a> secretariaat <a href="\[https://twitter.com/hashtag/Antwerpen?src=hash\\\&amp;ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/hashtag/Antwerpen?src=hash\&amp;ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">#Antwerpen</a> opnieuw vol te schilderen en ‘werk’ af te maken! Wie herkent deze man? <a href="\[https://twitter.com/VBAntwerpen?ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/VBAntwerpen?ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">@vbantwerpen</a> <a href="\[https://twitter.com/PZAntwerpen?ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/PZAntwerpen?ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">@PZAntwerpen</a> <a href="">\[pic.twitter.com/xAFPsH8irK\](http://pic.twitter.com/xAFPsH8irK)</a></p>\\\&mdash; Filip Dewinter (@FDW\\\_VB) <a href="\[https://twitter.com/FDW\\\_VB/status/1165972391442419713?ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/FDW\_VB/status/1165972391442419713?ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">August 26, 2019</a></blockquote> <script async src="\[https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\](https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js)" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And when you edit the page and look at the code it made this from it:

```
<blockquote> <p dir="ltr">Moedige man jaagt graffitispuiter die <a href="\[https://twitter.com/VBAntwerpen?ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/VBAntwerpen?ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">@VBAntwerpen</a> secretariaat vandaliseert weg... Dank! <a href="">\[pic.twitter.com/QELeigJSff\](http://pic.twitter.com/QELeigJSff)</a></p> \\\&mdash; Filip Dewinter (@FDW\\\_VB) <a href="\[https://twitter.com/FDW\\\_VB/status/1165967353173151744?ref\\\_src=twsrc%5Etfw\](https://twitter.com/FDW\_VB/status/1165967353173151744?ref\_src=twsrc%5Etfw)">August 26, 2019</a></blockquote>
```

Anybody had this before or knows how to prevent this from happening?